# Segmenting multiple sites in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, advanced-segments

Our company uses templates in order to build websites for multiple clients. In addition to tracking each site's analytics individually, I also added a tag manager code for an aggregate GA account. The tag fires like a UA code on every page on every site so that we can look at all of our data en masse.

Here's the problem: I'd like to be able to segment based on template edition so that we can review what works and what doesn't based on the template. I'm using a hostname filter on segments in order to identify them. Unfortunately, we have more sites on some of these templates than the segment will allow (we've capped out).

Is there a better way to do this, or at least a way to build a segment that will allow us to look at all of our templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segments are always limited in how much of them you can use in analysis.

The only way I think to tackle this problem is always creating custom reports for whatever analysis you want to do and then exporting this data in excel to Do further analysis.

Please note that based on traffic to these websites the custom reports may be sampled and you can request insampled if you are a premium user.